# IE10 blocks a deployer plugin which is working fine on IE8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-8, windows-8.1, activex, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make a deployer plugin,which consists of deploy.dll,deploy.inf and an exe file which will be triggered when the user loads the page. I followed the steps from the following Microsoft page(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974%28VS.85%29.aspx),

it is working fine for IE8 , I sigend the dll files and cab files using a test CA signed certificate and I imported the CA certificate to Trusted CA certs using Microsoft management console.

The above steps make the plugin to work fine for IE8 on windows 7.

when I tried to test the same plugin on IE10 on Windows 8 and 8.1,
IE says IE blocked the plugin from installing as deploy.dll is not trusted.

I followed the same steps what I did for IE8.

I'm not sure what went wrong, please some one help me to resolve this issue.

Is there any security related restrictions by microsoft on IE10 on Win8 , 8.1?

as the same plugin works fine on IE11 , IE10 on Windows 7 , and it is not working only on IE 10 which comes with windows 8 , 8.1 OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have some bad news for you: You're working with a technology that is obsolete. ActiveX support is being removed from Microsoft's browsers.

Windows 8 and IE10 started the process of deprecating the ActiveX technology in the browser. ActiveX has been a constant source of major security issues for IE, and with the improvements in built-in browser capabilities in recent years, it was also becoming less and less useful. So Microsoft have started removing ActiveX support from its browsers.

In IE10 and IE11 under Windows 8 it is partially disabled -- in full standards mode, only a small number of well known and trusted controls are supported; all others are blocked. In compatibility mode, it is still possible to run ActiveX controls just as before, but you also lose some of the more modern browser features.

In Microsoft's latest browser, Edge (the replacement for IE that comes with Windows 10) you don't even have the option of compatibility mode: ActiveX support is completely removed.

So the short-term answer here is that if you want to run ActiveX controls in IE10 and IE11, you need to set the browser into compatibility mode.

But the longer-term answer is that you're going to have to switch away from ActiveX as a technology for browser controls, and switch to HTML5 and JavaScript.